# add object to arraylist from another class

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I got a problem. I want to add an object named `Transactions` which is this one:

```
public class Transaction {
private float value;
private int transaction_date;
private String description;

public Transaction(float value, int transaction_date, String description){
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.transaction_date = transaction_date;
    this.description = description;
}

public float getValue(){
    return value;
}
public int getTransaction_date(){
    return transaction_date;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
```

to an `ArrayList` in my `main activity`.
Okay as far not that much of a problem. But how can I do this from another activity where I want to set the required variables (in my case the value, transaction_date and description)?
Here is my Activity where I want to set the values (yes I know that there are no variable inputs yet):

```
public class AddMoneyTransaction extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText depositInputSix;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money_transaction);

    //transaction list

    populateTransactionList();
    populateListView();

    //setup the button

    Button addDepositButton;
    addDepositButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addDepositButton);

    //make it work

    addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view) {


                }
            });
}

//populated transaction list

protected void populateTransactionList() {

    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(1,19,"monday"));
    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(2,20,"tuesday"));
    myTransactions.add(new Transaction(3,21,"wednesday"));


}

//populated list view

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Transaction> adapter = new AssetsOverview.LastTransactionsListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.last_transactions_listView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class LastTransactionsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction>{
    public LastTransactionsListAdapter(){
        super(AddMoneyTransaction.this, R.layout.transaction_list_view, myTransactions);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //make sure there is a view to work with (maybe null)
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_view, parent, false);
        }

        //find a transaction to work with

        Transaction currentTransaction = myTransactions.get(position);

        // fill the view:
        //    value
        TextView valueView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionValueView);
        valueView.setText(currentTransaction.getValue() + "$");

        //    date
        TextView dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionDateView);
        dateView.setText(currentTransaction.getTransaction_date() + "");

        //    description
        TextView descriptionView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transactionDesciptionView);
        descriptionView.setText(currentTransaction.getDescription());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can please help me with this since I did not find anything helpful. Please tell me if you need more information...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your *myTransactions* list is defined inside parent class AppCompatActivity. The problem in

```
addDepositButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });
```

seems to be that *myTransactions* is not defined as a final variable.

When you create a new anonymous *OnClickListener*, what the compiler does is it provides to *OnClickListener* constructor a reference to your *myTransactions*, if *myTransactions* is used inside the *onClick* method. This *myTransactions* cannot be changed later and must therefore be final.

So for the solution, I would try adding **final** keyword in the definition of *myTransactions*.

Comment: I can not do this because my ArrayList is placed in my MainActivity, not in the AddMoneyTransaction class. It is just meant to add objects to the MainActivity.

Comment: Then make another variable myTransactions2, mark it final and value equal to myTransactions. Then use that. Hack.